# Counting co-occurrence across three columns while ignoring duplicates

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (a lot larger in reality).

| Family1 | Family2 | Family3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | B |
| B | A | B |
| B | C | C |

Now there are three requirements:

- I have to count the co-occurrence of the values from Family1, Family2 and Family3.
- The co-occurrence should not be duplicated.
- Reverse of values' co-occurrence should not be added as unique, so A-B is the same as B-A.

For the above case, I want family and related family with their co-occurrence. So the output should be like

| family | related_family | co-occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | 2 |
| C | B | 1 |

Based on these three cases I have written a query.

```py
output_one = sqldf("""
select family, related_family, sum(cooccurence) as Cooccurence  from
(
select Family1 family, Family2 related_family, count(*) cooccurence 
from ds_neighbours 
WHERE Family1!= Family2 and Family2 != Family1
GROUP BY Family1, Family2
UNION
select Family2 family, Family3 related_family, count(*) cooccurence 
from ds_neighbours 
WHERE Family2 != Family3 and Family3 != Family2
GROUP BY Family2, Family3
UNION
select Family1 family, Family3 related_family, count(*) cooccurence 
from ds_neighbours 
WHERE Family1 != Family3 and Family3 != Family1
GROUP BY Family1, Family3
)
WHERE cooccurence > 25 group by family, related_family
ORDER BY cooccurence DESC
""")
```

Now my query is not able to handle case 3 where occurrence of family and related_family skills in reverse is counted as unique.
Ex - linux as family and cplusplus as related_family, and cplusplus as family and linux as related_family is counted as unique and vice versa.

And my requirement is that it should not be a unique record. How do I do this?

Comment: Yes it's a long list data set and hard to add it there. 
but on a whole I just wanted to get family and related family from screenshot one Family1, Family2, Family 3 and add the primary skills as family into another data set and their other skill as related family and the co-occurrence of the combined string as count across the data set from first one.

Ex - in screenshot one first raw I have agile_project_manager, other and other.
So in next one the family will be other and related family will be agile_project_manager along with the co-occurrence count of the string in the set.

Comment: This combination can be into reverse.
Like agile_project_manager and others
       others and agile_project_manager. so in such case this should not be considered as unique entry. This is ideally the same.

Comment: @cottontail added as an example with few records

Comment: So if this the combination of the string from Family1 Family2 and Family3 occurs again the count should be increased.
As you stated in this case the count will increased by 1.
And ABB and BAA should be counted as same string and because this been occurred two time count will be increased by 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251377/discussion-between-cottontail-and-rahul-anand).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to find the unique pairs and count the occurrences of each pair.

```py
new_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        ds_neighbours[['Family1', 'Family2', 'Family3']]
        .stack()
        .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().unique())
        .tolist(), 
        columns=['family', 'related_family'])
    .groupby(['family', 'related_family'], as_index=False).agg(co_occurrence=('family', 'size'))
)
```

[image: res]

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. Appreciate your response.!!